# haskell - Using withState in place of put

Tags: haskell, monads

I have written numbering tree in inorder. As you can see, I used `put`. Is it possible to use `withState` here ?

```
renumberTree2Inorder :: Tree a -> StateT Int Identity (Tree Int)
renumberTree2Inorder Empty = return Empty
renumberTree2Inorder (Node _ l r) = (renumberTree2Inorder l) >>= (\l' -> 
        get >>= (\i -> put (i + 1) >>= (\_ -> renumberTree2Inorder r) >>= (\r' -> return (Node i l' r'))))



renumberTree2Inorder' :: Tree a -> Tree Int
renumberTree2Inorder' t = evalState (renumberTree2Inorder t) 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here's what `withState` looks like:

```
renumberTree2Inorder :: Tree a -> StateT Int Identity (Tree Int)
renumberTree2Inorder Empty =
  return Empty
renumberTree2Inorder (Node _ l r) = do
  l' <- renumberTree2Inorder l
  i <- get
  withState (+ 1) $ do
    r' <- renumberTree2Inorder r
    return (Node i l' r')
```

You still need the `i <- get` so you can construct the `Node` at the end.

Comment: I don't think this use of `withState` makes any sense, you only call it on `get` so it is precisely `modify (+1) >> get`. `withState` should probably be applied to the recursive case.